# How to get Emmet to work in VS code on windows

Tags: windows, settings, emmet, abbreviation

Attempting to use Emmet in VS code
the setting has Emmet show abbreviation Suggestions Checked
emmet show expanded abbreviation as always
emmet show suggestions as snippets checked if True
Emmet trigger expansion on tab checked

Still Emmet not working in VS code please advise?

I have Tried uninstalling and re-downloading VS Code. I am unchecking the boxes and rechecking the boxes.